# Get all keys from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary containing a list, like this:

```
{"items": [{"name": "Orange", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Apple", "cost": 10}]}
```

Would it be possible to get the keys "name" and "cost" from both lists in some way?
It's just for the reason that I don't want to add another line every time I add something new to the dictionary in the same list.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you are trying to achieve? Maybe give us the code you currently have and we can give further guidance

Comment: what data representation do you want? i think the dictionaries inside the list are what you want. your purpose is unclear.

Comment: What I want is to extract both the "name" and the "cost" from the dictionaries inside the list, but I already got a decent answer. :P

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the -1. There was no particular code together with this, I wanted to use this for a couple of things. I think my explanation was sufficent enough, I explained I wanted to get the values of "name" and "cost" from both dictionaries in the list, because I don't want to add a new line every time to get them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that, by getting the keys you meant the values associated with those keys.

`a['items']` is a list. Just iterate through it and access the `name` and `cost` values as you would access any dictionary.

```
>>> a_dict = {"items": [{"name": "Orange", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Apple", "cost": 10}]}
>>> for a_d in a_dict['items']:
        print 'Name: {} Cost: {}'.format(a_d['name'], a_d['cost'])
```

This gives:

```
Name: Orange Cost: 5
Name: Apple Cost: 10
```

If infact you wanted the key names of the dictionaries in the list `a['items']` you can get them using `.keys()`:

```
>>> for a_d in a_dict['items']:
        print a_d.keys()
```

This gives:

```
['cost', 'name']
['cost', 'name']
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid code duplication is to use a function.

```
def get_name_and_cost(d):
    return d['name'], d['cost']

for d in lst['items']:
    name, cost = get_name_and_cost(d)
    print(name, cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one group of 'items', this will go through each group in your dictionary.

```
d = {"fruit": [{"name": "Orange", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Apple", "cost": 10}],
    "vegetables": [{"name": "carrot", "cost": 5}, {"name": "eggplant", "cost": 10}]}

for group, items in d.items():
    for item in items:
        print item['name']  

>>>
carrot
eggplant
Orange
Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a more dynamic, reusable approach would be to make a function.

```
def get_values(d, *keys):
    t = []
    for k in keys:
        if k in d.keys():
            t.append(d[k])
        else:
            t.append(None)
    return t
```

or

```
def get_values(d, *keys):
    return [ d[k] if k in d.keys() else none for k in keys]
```

then you can do stuff like this!

```
>>> d = {"items": [{"name": "Orange", "cost": 5}, {"name": "Apple", "cost": 10}]}
>>> for item in d["items"]:
...     print "Name {}, Cost {}".format(*get_values(item, "name", "cost"))
...
Name Orange, Cost 5
Name Apple, Cost 10
```